# Wordpress get the child pages of current page

Tags: child-pages, get-children, get-the-id

I want to display the child pages of the current page you are on.

`<?php wp_list_pages('child_of=67&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=') ?>`

If I give the id number like above it works perfectly like this:

[image: works perfectly]

However I want to use this as a template for multiple pages, but when I use the ID or get Id or echoing the ID, it also take the sibling pages of the parent page. Which I don't need.

`<?php wp_list_pages('child_of=the_ID()&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=') ?>`

[image: Gets the siblings of the parent pages as well]

I can't figure it out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$current_page_id = get_the_ID();
wp_list_pages("child_of={$current_page_id}&sort_column=menu_order&title_li="); ?>
```

Please check the above code

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!